# php cannot write new line, file gets overwirtten

Tags: php, fopen

I have read a lot of questions, none of which worked. I have a txt file. The first line contains headers separated by a tab "\n". Now when i post to this file I want it to take the values and separate them by a tab and then write them on a new line of the txt file. But when I run it, it just overwrites the first line.

```
<?php
$post = $_POST;
$myFile = 'test.txt';
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w');
$columns = "";
foreach ($post as $key => $value){

    $columns .= $value . "\t"; 

}
fwrite($fh, $columns . PHP_EOL);
fclose($fh);
?>
```

Comment: Ive already tried \r\n and all that and finally tried EOL and still first line of file gets overwritten

Comment: Try `$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a');` if you don't want to overwrite content. Using `w` overwrites and `a` or `a+` appends.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for being so dumb. Worked!

Comment: @JasonStorey: Consider marking any of the two answers as accepted, when you are able to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `a` instead `w`:

```
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a');
```

From [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php):

> 'w'    Open for writing only; **place the file pointer at the beginning of
>   the file and truncate the file to zero length**. If the file does not
>   exist, attempt to create it.
>
> 'a'    Open for writing only; **place the file pointer at the end of the
>   file**. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a');` if you don't want to overwrite content.

Using `w` overwrites, while `a` or `a+` appends.

For more information on the [`fwrite()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) function, you can consult the PHP manual.

- **http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php**

Also consult the PHP manual on `fopen()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

`'a'` Open for writing only; place the file pointer at the end of the file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

`'a+'`  Open for reading and writing; place the file pointer at the end of the file. If the file does not exist, attempt to create it.

Answer (score 0):

`w` is used for writing which means anything before gets overwritten.

Change the following line:

```
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'w'); //w = write
```

To

```
$fh = fopen($myFile, 'a'); //a = append
```

It should fix the issue for you.